# Question about using ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I really do not know if the title is appropriate or not.

I have 2 options:
OPTION 1:

```
Class A {
   ArrayList<B> BList = new ArrayList<B>();

   public B[] getBList() {
       return (B[])BList.toArray();
   }
}

Class Facade {
   public B[] getAllB(){
       A a = new A();
       return a.getBList();
   }
}
```

OPTION 2:

```
Class A {
   ArrayList<B> BList = new ArrayList<B>();

   public ArrayList getBList() {
       return BList;
   }
}

Class Facade {
   public B[] getAllB(){
       A a = new A();
       ArrayList BList = a.getBList();
       return (B[])BList.toArray();
   }
}
```

Which option should i use ?

Comment: The array returned by `ArrayList.toArray` will actually have a runtime type of `Object[]`. Casting it may have unexpected consequences...

Answer (score 3):

Use collection classes, unless you have a specific reason to use arrays. So, I'd choose option 2.

There are a number of other comments that can be made about your code.

First, It's better to [program to an interface, not an implementation](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples.html) - make the member variable `BList` in class `A` a `List<B>` instead of an `ArrayList<B>`. Also, member variables should be `private` (unless there's a very good reason for them not to be `private`). Third, use generics whenever possible - why does your method `getBList()` return a raw `ArrayList`? The de-facto naming standard for variables in Java is [camel case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), starting with a lower-case letter. So don't call the member variable `BList`, but `bList` (or some other, better name).

```
class A {
    private List<B> bList = new ArrayList<B>();

    public List<B> getBList() {
        return bList;
    }
}
```

Is it really necessary for class `Facade` to return a `B[]`?

Another point to consider is to make your class `A` immutable, because unexpected things might happen if you'd get the list from an `A` object, and then add or remove elements from the list (the list inside your `A` object will also be changed and that can be confusing). You'd have to return a read-only view of the list in your `getBList()` method:

```
public List<B> getBList() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(bList);
}
```

Comment: thanks for that, it is very useful for me. I have modified it :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a strong preference either way. However, I notice you're using an array to return the list's contents, perhaps in an attempt to make it immutable. I recommend, instead, using [Collections.unmodifiableList](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)).

Comment: Good basic idea. I much prefer Google's Guava Immutable collections objects, as they are setup for generic type safety.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only difference is whether Class A is part of the public interface of your component.

If it's not (e.g. only the Facade counts to the public interface), then **it does not matter**.

If Class A is part of the public interface, i'd go with Option 1.

Comment: Class A is actually hidden from the users, the GUI will interact directly with the facade class

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really need too, where the native formt of something is bytes[] for something like images, one should always return Collection types in an API for a many of something rather than an array. In your case wrap the original Collection using Collections.unmodifiableXXX( ...).